# KVM virsh attach-disk does not honour device letter

Tags: storage, virtualization, virtual-machine, kvm

I use the following command to attach a disk to a running KVM virtual server:

```
virsh attach-disk vps_89 /dev/nbd31 --target vdc --driver tap
```

The disk is attached correctly. However, the disk is not attached as `vdc` inside the virtual server. I know the documentation says that the `--target` parameter is only giving a "hint" to the virtual server, but I can't really believe there is NO way to force the disk to be attached as a certain device (at least on Linux).

I am controlling my virtual servers through scripts and I must trust that the disk is attached to the exact device as I tell it to.

When I detach the disk using this:

```
virsh detach-disk vps_89 --target vdc
```

Then re-attaching the same disk again, the device-ID seems to be increamented each time, i.e `vdc`, `vdd`, `vde`, `vdf` etc... (totally ignoring my `--target` param)

Does anyone know a good (and reliable) way of attaching disks to KVM in a predictable way?

Answer (score 5):

According to RedHat [1] and libvirt [2] this is not a bug, it's a feature:

> The actual device name specified is not guaranteed to map to the
>   device name in the guest OS. Treat it as a device ordering hint.

The only available solution is to use UUID (/dev/disk/by-uuid/) for handling disk inside virtual machine.

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693372
2. http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html

Comment: This is not entirely true. It is not the ONLY way. I ended up using /dev/disk/by-path as I know what PCI port I attach the drive to.

Comment: You can pass the `--serial mydiskname` option to `virsh attach-disk`, and the disk will then appear as e.g. `/dev/disk/by-id/virtio-mydiskname`. But I also agree being forced to give a target (it's mandatory) that is totally ignored is pretty annoying. It seems that `--target` should be optional if it's only a "hint".